# C# UWP create check-list table programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have task to create in C# UWP user created check-list. 
But I have stuck from the beginning cause XAML is new for me, so I have no idea what to start from.
So, I have textbox to enter title, task or subtask to in listbox (priviously added to) selected task.

this is my xaml how it looks like now:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Table1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Table1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="71" Margin="71,247,0,0" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="title" Content="Add Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="task" Content="Add Task" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="subtask" Content="Add Subtask" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="71,354,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401,483,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_Click"/>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

There are the code:

```
public class subtasks
        {
            public string parent { get; set; }
            public string subtask { get; set; }

            public subtasks(string parenti, string subtaski)
            {
                parent = parenti;
                subtask = subtaski;
            }

            public  void setsub(string parenti, string sub)
            {
                parent = parenti;
                subtask = sub;
            }
        }


        List<string> Tasks = new List<string>();
        List<subtasks> sub = new List<subtasks>();

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string parent = "";
            string Title;
            string Task;
            string Subtask;

            if (title.IsChecked==true)
            {
                Title = txt.Text;
                adding(Title, parent, 1);
            }
            else if (task.IsChecked==true)
            {
                Task = txt.Text;
                adding(Task, parent, 2);
            }
            else if (subtask.IsChecked==true)
            {
                parent = listbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Subtask = txt.Text;
                adding(Subtask, parent, 3);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void adding(string str, string par, int x)
        {
            subtasks subi = new subtasks(par,str);
            RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
            TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
            if (x==1)
            {
                print(str);
            }
            else if (x==2)
            {
                Tasks.Add(str);
                listbox.Items.Add(str);
                text.Text = str;
                print(str);


            }
            else
            {
                sub.Add(subi);
                print(str);
            }
        }

        private void print(string title)
        {
            int step = 0;
            Grid gridwin = new Grid();
            gridwin.Children.Clear();
            RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
            TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
            text.Text = title;
            Grid.SetColumn(text, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(text, step);
            step++;


            for (int i = 0; i < Tasks.Count; i++)
            {
                text.Text = Tasks[i].ToString();
                gridwin.Children.Add(text);
                Grid.SetColumn(text, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(text, step);
                step++;
                for (int k = 0; k < sub.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (sub[k].parent == Tasks[i])
                    {
                        text.Text = sub[k].subtask.ToString();
                        gridwin.Children.Add(text);
                        Grid.SetColumn(text, 0);
                        Grid.SetRow(text, step);
                        step++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you see I need to clear and put data every time the button is clicked, cause you never know when user will decide to add new subtask for previously added task. So, the question is, how to make the table with column1 with tasks and subtasks and column2 which is chekbox.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to probably do is to create a `DataTemplate`. You use this to specify how list items should be displayed and formatted. This way you can specify you want to lay them out as a `Grid` with two columns like description and `CheckBox`. Take a look into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/xaml-basics-ui#part-3-add-a-datatemplate-to-display-your-data) to see some examples of `DataTemplates`. You can also see the [Azure Mobile Apps quickstart for UWP](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-mobile-apps-uwp-quickstart), because although it is focused on demonstrating Microsoft Azure integration to UWP, it is actually a to-do app, which should give you some inspiration for building your own.

The layout could look like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="71,354,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
              <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You can see my code is also using `{Binding}` syntax, which you will also need to learn a bit about to be able to know when the user has checked a to-do item in the list.  I suggest you to take a look at a simple tutorial sample like [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_data_binding.htm). In fact, data-binding is one of the most important things when building XAML-based apps and when you get to understand this concept, it will help you a lot on the way to becoming a UWP ninja :-) .

Comment: If I create a child Textblock do I still need binding?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use the UWP `DataGrid` with `CheckBox`?

**XAML**

```
<toolkit:DataGrid Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind myItemsToBind}"
x:Name="dgwDeviceSPNs" MinWidth="100"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent" 
AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CanUserSortColumns="False"
CanUserReorderColumns="True"
RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative=""
CanUserResizeColumns="True"         
MaxColumnWidth="200"
FrozenColumnCount="0"
GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
HeadersVisibility="None"
IsReadOnly="True" 
RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
SelectionMode="Single">
<toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
 <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="10">
  <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="2">
     <CheckBox ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Name}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Name}"></CheckBox> 
     </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```